# How to find git configuration error for pushing to a remote repository?

Tags: git, github, push

I am in the process of switching from Mercurial to Git and have some beginner's problems I would appreciate to be helped with... Concretely, I created a local git repository and one on GitHub, now I am trying to push the local repo with `git push -u origin master`. 
As a reply I am getting:

```
remote: Permission to FrancescaY/TestApp.git denied to XYZ.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/FrancescaY/TestApp.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

where XYZ is occasionally a name (login name) of a colleague who does not have anything to do with this task. I have tried my best to find out where this XYZ setting is stored to delete / modify it, but was unable to.
I would appreciate assistance with how to find the reason of this error resp. where can that name be stored?

PS. I checked it that my name and email address on GitHub are the same as in git global and local configurations; the name XYZ does not occur anywhere.

Comment: Hint: [git credential manager](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+credential+manager)

Comment: @phd Thank you; I installed MS Git credential manager and dumped  git credential-manager config. The only possibly relevant settings there were user.name and user.email, which are mine, do not have anything to do with that XYZ and which I already knew. Did you mean that?

Comment: I found out that XYZ has a github account, and when I added him as a contributor (and he accepted), I was able to push. But this is not the solution I am looking for. I want just to get rid of this dependence, I guess he did something git-relevant from the machine I am presently working at. Can this be done without complete re-installation of Git?

Comment: My final comment to this topic: being unable to find out the reason, I uninstalled the whole of the Git system on my machine (which actually used TortoiseGit) and installed everything anew, from git-scm. Since then the behavior is as expected,